# Pass array of array from C# Page Load to use in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, client-side, server-side

In Page_Load on server side, I got an array of array as:

```
[['1_1','2_1','3_1','4_1'],['1_2','2_2','3_2','4_2'],....]
```

(Image to example):
[image]

How can I pass that array to client to use in javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, serialize this array and on the page create a JavaScript variable with this serialized value. E.g.

In C#, serialize it -

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().serialize(Object)
```

In JS access it -

```
var arr = <%= serializedArray %>
```

Other way, when the page loads, create ajax to fetch this data. Refer this [article](http://www.cheezycode.com/2015/08/create-html-table-using-jquery-ajax.html)

Comment: Work great. Thank you so much.